# Finding the subsets of a set

Tags: set, scheme, racket

I am trying to write a procedure that finds the power set of a list, that is, the set of 2<sup>n</sup> subsets (where *n* is the number of elements in the list). I simply quite find all the subsets. I feel my code is a lot more work than it should be.

```
(define (element-of-set? x set)
  (cond ((null? set) false)
        ((not(pair? set)) (display "not a set\n") false)
        ((equal? x (car set)) true)
        (else (element-of-set? x (cdr set)))))

(define (length set)
  (define (length-iter a len )
    (if (null? a)
        len
        (length-iter (cdr a) (+ 1 len))))
  (length-iter set 0))

(define (adjoin-set x set)
  (if (element-of-set? x set)
      set
      (cons x set)))

(define (conS x w )
  (cond ((null? w) '())
        (else(cons (cons (car x) (cons (car w) '())) (conS x (cdr w))))))

(define (helper s)
  (define (help s newS len)

    (if (<= len 0) newS
        (help (cdr s)(append (adjoin-set s newS) (conS s (cdr s)))(- len 1))))
  (help s '() (length s)))

(define (trim s)
  (let helper((s s) (newS '()) (len (length s)))
    (cond ((<= len 0) newS) 
          ((null?(cdr(car s)))
                 (helper (cdr s) newS(- len 1)))
          (else (helper (cdr s) (adjoin-set (car s) newS) (- len 1))))))

(define (subsets x)
  (define (sub x newSet)
    (if (null? x) newSet
        (sub (cdr x) (adjoin-set (cons (car x) '())
                                 (adjoin-set '() newSet)))))
  (sub x (trim (helper x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in general it's okay, if you need to define all of those yourself (in particular `length` and `element-of-set?` that is. `trim` looks a bit complicated for what it does: If you want to skip single element lists (why?), write it like that, no need for the accumulator and the `length` call.

The input set should be cleaned up once before the subset generation though, then you won't have to filter the result for duplicates.

- `conS`, `helper` and `trim` are bad names. The first one is a compatibility issue since you'll find Lisps that are case-insensitive, which will then overwrite the regular `cons`. Both `conS` and `helper` don't say anything at all about what they do. `trim` essentially the same, a little better maybe. In general, stick with `scheme-names-with-dashes-in-between`, descriptive names and no camel case.
- You sometimes skip the space between `)_(` and add spaces where they don't belong, like `_)` which looks messy. Indentation is sometimes a bit off, e.g. the `if` in `subsets` has the first case on the same line as the `if`.